# VBA create a version 10 pivot table in an xls file via Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel-2007, excel-2003, pivot-table

I need to create xlPivotTableVersion10 pivot tables (Excel 2003 compatible) via a macro that I run on my computer which has Excel 2007 on it.
I run the macro from a a source file. I have another file (WkbVar) which is .xls and opened in [compatible mode] in which I want to create several pivot tables. I have managed to create a connection to my external Access database (DOH Location inventory V6) from which I get my datasource as well as a pivot cache (pc) with this connection.

```
Set pc = WkbVar.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal,
SourceData:=WkbVar.Connections("DOH Location inventory V6") _
, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
With pc
.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=WksAlertesVar.Range("A9"),TableName:="PivotTable_0", _
DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
End With
```

The pivot cache seems to be created just fine but then I get a type 1004 "application defined of object-define" error at the ".CreatePivotTable [...] DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10" line.

I have tried a couple variations and here is a recap of what I get :

- **pivot cache Version**:=xlPivotTableversion10 + **pivot table** DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableversion10 => 1004 error
- **pivot cache Version**:=xlPivotTableversion10 + **pivot table** DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableversion12 => 1004 error
- **pivot cache Version**:=xlPivotTableversion12 + **pivot table** DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableversion10 => 5 error "invalid procedure call"
- **pivot cache Version**:=xlPivotTableversion12 + **pivot table** DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableversion12 => works OK but it creates an Excel 2007 pivot table, which is not compatible for filters and refresh in xls files.

If I stop the macro after having created my connection and create a pivot table by hand still in [compatibility mode], it works as desired : I get an Excel 2003 pivot table. Which makes me think that what I am trying to do is possible, I just can't seem to code it right...

If anyone has any hint on how to create Excel 2003 pivot tables in xls files but via Excel 2007 application and VBA, I would very appreciate your knowledge-sharing.

Sincerely,
J.

--------------  edit (following Karter's comment)

Indeed there seems to be a problem with using an external source for my pivot table. After a bit more of searching and testing, I came up with the following work around :

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
.Connection = Array( )'HERE GOES ALL THE DATA RELATIVE TO MY CONNECTION TO THE ACCESS DATABASE
.CommandType = xlCmdTable
.CommandText = Array( _ 'here is the SQL string to select some data from a specific table I have in my Access database
"SELECT *" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM [DOH historique avec libelles] WHERE [DOH historique avec libelles]![Numero Site Gestionnaire] = " & NoSite _
)
.MaintainConnection = False
.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ActiveWorksheet.Range("A9"), TableName:="PivotTable_0", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
End With
```

when before I would first add a connection with just the "DATA RELATIVE TO MY CONNECTION..." information and no .CommandType, .CommandText etc. parameters.

I am not very familiar with connections parameters but I guess this trick has something to do with the external source issue highlighted by Karter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual source connection is not compatible -- if you use an xldatabase as the source, it works fine:

```
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Sheet5!R1C1:R2C3", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(Sheet7.[A1], "testpivot1", , xlPivotTableVersion10)
```

I know that when I coded pivot tables in Excel 2003 you had to manually adjust the connection string of the pivot table, so I think that may be causing your issues. I'll see if I can find an old example.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look into my question. I have edited my question to report some changes I made to my initial code to work around the issue, and I think it might indeed be related to internal / external source issue you mention.